# how do I make the blue lines go away?

Tags: xcode

Xcode recently updated itself to Version 14.0 (14A309), when it loads, it all looks normal, but eventually all these blue lines appear. [image: xcode 14 blue line issue]

I have tried changing the setting Editor > Canvas > Bounds Rectangles

Every time I select the Main Storyboard, even if this setting is unchecked, in about a minute, it is automatically checked off and the blue lines reappear.  Unchecking doesn't make lines disappear on storyboard.  Then I have to uncheck it again, close Main Storyboard and reselect it. And the whole cycle starts again about a minute later.

Seems like a bug in this new version of xcode.  Anyone else seeing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reverted from xcode 14 back to 13.4.1 and rebooted my computer and the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

same issue, I've also the same problem with my xcode, goto Editor then Canvas then tick and untick three times the on Bounds Rectangle option. But this is not a permanent solution[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsolW.png)